# Como ter acesso ao banco de dados de outra máquina

Tags: mysql

Galera, boa noite. 
É o seguinte:
Estou com um projeto de PHP com MySQL para ser entregue. Porém, estou fazendo desta maneira: Criei 3 máquinas virtuais no VMWare Workstation Pro, a do Cliente é Windows, a que fica somente o PHP é Ubuntu, e a que fica o banco de dados também é Ubuntu. A ideia é que seja uma simulação. Da máquina do Cliente, eu consigo acessar o site na máquina do PHP através do IP da máquina/nome_do_arquivo.php, consigo fazer isso sem problemas. O negócio é que eu fiz um formulário nesse site PHP para inserir dados no banco de dados que está em outra máquina.
Resumo da ópera: não estou conseguindo obter conexão com o banco de dados, ou seja, não consigo ter acesso remoto ao banco, mesmo tendo configurado o arquivo de conexão da maneira certa. Jà pesquisei em vários lugares, tanto nacionais como na gringa, e não achei nada. 
Se puderem me ajudar, ficarei muito grato!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Para permitir o acesso externo ao banco de dados mysql em um servidor remoto, é configurar-lo para acessos externos.

1. Acessar o arquivo **my.cnf** e modificar o parâmetro IP **bind-address  =  127.0.0.1** para **0.0.0.0**
2. Reiniciar o mysql
3. Acessar o mysql de dentro do servidor e dar as permissões de acesso a partir de qualquer IP. **mysql> GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '[senha]' WITH GRANT OPTION;**
4. Para finalizar atualizar os privilégios **mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;**

Comment: Não deu certo :/ ja desabilitei o firewall, ja configurei o GRANT no mysql, ja configurei o arquivo do mysql mas não conecta.. quando eu carrego a pagina de conexao.php nem aparece erro, fica em branco

Answer (score 0):

Você consegue se conectar ao MySQL a partir do seu próprio host? Se não, veja se ele está rodando.

```
sudo service mysql status
```

Se o status estiver como 'active', verifique se o arquivo /etc/mysql/my.cnf contém a linha bind-address 127.0.0.1 . Se sim, comente-a com # ou remova-a.

Verifique também se o seu firewall está ativo:

```
sudo ufw status verbose
```

Se estiver, pode ser necessário desbloquear a porta 3306 - ou outra definida como padrão.

```
sudo ufw allow from 192.168.* to any port 3306
```

Espero ter ajudado! Valeu!

Comment: Não deu certo :/ ja desabilitei o firewall, ja configurei o GRANT no mysql, ja configurei o arquivo do mysql mas não conecta.. quando eu carrego a pagina de conexao.php nem aparece erro, fica em branco

Comment: Alex, em qual parte não deu certo? Funciona localmente? Se funciona, utilize o heidisql (ou outro cliente) pra conectar remotamente. Há chances tbém de que seja problemas de configuração dos caminhos de rede. Somente depois utilize a sua aplicação ou página pra tentar o acesso. Vai reportando aí, quem sabe não encontramos o problema.